# Why darts have feathers?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, drag, aerodynamics

I have read that feathers stabilize the trajectory of a dart but I haven't found any description how they do this.

Any link or comment would be very welcome

Comment: They do something similar to the rifling of a rifle barrel: they impart a spin to a dart as it travels through the air, which helps keep it aerodynamically stable. These feathers are called "fletchings" or "fletches," by the way.

Comment: http://www.tap46home.plus.com/mechanics/ and in particular http://www.tap46home.plus.com/mechanics/arrowstab.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An aerodynamic structure is stable if the center of pressure is behind the center of mass.  You're probably familiar with the center of mass: its a point such that the forces of gravity and effects of inertia act as though all forces were directed through that point.  The center of pressure is the same idea: its a point such that the aerodynamic forces act as though they are all directed through that point.  If the center of pressure is behind the center of mass, any perturbation self corrects.  If the center is in front, the perturbations cause the structure to flip out of control.

It may help to visualize a dart flying straight.  Now let's say some forces pitched it upwards so that it was pointing part way towards the ceiling.  The feathers would be behind and below the center of mass, and the oncoming air would push the feathers back and upwards.  Pushing the back part of the dart up causes the dart to resume flying straight (or roughly a 0 angle of attack).

Now visualize throwing a dart backwards, and pretend it again pitched slightly upwards.  Now the feathers will be in front and above the center of mass.  The oncoming air would push the feathers back and upwards.  However, because now the feathers are on the front of the structure (since we threw it backwards), this causes the dart to pitch even further upwards.  In fact, if given enough time, the dart will turn all the way around, and stabilize in the forward direction again!